# In which language is cmd.exe written?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

> Command Prompt, also known as cmd.exe or cmd (after its executable
>   file name), is the command-line interpreter on Windows NT, Windows CE,
>   OS/2 and eComStation operating systems. It is the counterpart of
>   COMMAND.COM in DOS and Windows 9x systems (where it is also called
>   "MS-DOS Prompt"), and analogous to the Unix shells used on Unix-like
>   systems.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)

I have searched everywhere but could not get an answer for this question.

Each website focuses on the fact that [batch language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) is used in [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) but I could not find the language in which it is written.

---

So my question is:

**What is the language that was used to write command-prompt or cmd.exe in Windows?**

Comment: Microsoft are very into Open Source these days - try asking them - I am sure they'll clarify and provide you the source.

Comment: It's probably C or C++, but why do you want to know? What are you going to do with the answer?

Comment: @CodeCaster pure curiosity

Comment: You might be interested in ReactOS, which has a version of cmd source code written in C: https://doxygen.reactos.org/db/d4f/base_2shell_2cmd_2cmd_8c_source.html

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Great find!

Comment: They use almost entirely C, C++, and C# for Windows. Some areas of code are hand tuned/hand written assembly.  C# is new comparing to CMD and used for the newest layers and it's not a good Idea to create CMD with assembly so, It's probably C or C++ as @CodeCaster said. When you read the story of Windows OS you will see the important influence of unix on Windows Kernel and you will conclude that CMD is written with C and maybe now they started using C++ (or both). If you find a response give us a link please I want to be sure about my conclusion :p

Comment: @MarkSetchell How will I ask them ?

Comment: The imports it depends on makes it is likely to be a mix of C and C++.  CRT functions like longjmp, calloc, free indicate C code, might well be ancient and hark back to the command.com days.   It clearly also uses C++ exception handling, C++ is their weapon of choice for all recent code development.  Mixing is not uncommon.

Comment: CMD was written for OS/2 (in partnership between Microsoft and IBM). Initially NT was supposed to be NT OS/2, but the business partnership between IBM and Microsoft ended. Microsoft switched the main user interface to Windows instead and ported CMD to its new Win32 API. It is unlikely that cmd.exe shares code in common with DOS COMMAND.COM, which would have been written in assembly language, whereas CMD needed to be written in portable C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file, when opened in a text editor, contains the path `onecore\base\cmd\maxpathawarestring.cpp`, which would indicate that at least one source file is written in C++.

Addendums from [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51402079/in-which-language-is-cmd-exe-written/51402401?noredirect=1#comment89776872_51402079):

> The imports it depends on makes it is likely to be a mix of C and C++. CRT functions like `longjmp`, `calloc`, `free` indicate C code, might well be ancient and hark back to the command.com days. It clearly also uses C++ exception handling, C++ is their weapon of choice for all recent code development. Mixing is not uncommon.

And [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51402079/in-which-language-is-cmd-exe-written/51402401?noredirect=1#comment89795011_51402401):

> under a debugger it's obvious that recent additions to CMD have been written in C++. `x cmd!*::*` shows significant use of the C++ `std` namespace
>
> [...]
>
> But CMD is still mostly C, not C++. Its commands and support functions are implemented as C functions such as `eExit`, `eChdir`, `ParseStatement`, `SearchForExecutable`, and `ExecPgm`. They haven't ported all of this old C code to an OOP design.

So I'd go with a mix of C and C++.

Comment: I would add that there are certain bugs in the old code base that have become defacto features that will likely never be fixed and could be difficult to replicate in a complete C++ oriented refactor.

Answer (score 2):

As **officially confirmed** by MS' Rich Turner, *originally* it's written in C

> Cmd is a Win32 app written entirely in 'C' - this is important since one of the key goals of NT was to be portable across many different processor and machine architectures
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/rumors-of-cmds-death-have-been-greatly-exaggerated/

but parts of it were migrated to C++ as of now

> ## Inside the Windows Console
>
> Windows Console is a traditional Win32 executable and, though it was originally written in 'C', much of the code is being migrated to modern C++ as the team modernizes and modularizes Console's codebase.
>
> > For those who care about such things: Many have asked whether Windows is written in C or C++. The answer is that - despite NT's Object-Based design - like most OS', Windows is almost entirely written in 'C'. Why? C++ introduces a cost in terms of memory footprint, and code execution overhead. Even today, the hidden costs of code written in C++ can be surprising, but back in the late 1990's, when [memory cost ~$60/MB](http://www.jcmit.net/memoryprice.htm) (yes … $60 per ***MEGABYTE***!), the hidden memory cost of vtables etc. was significant. In addition, the cost of virtual-method call indirection and object-dereferencing could result in very significant performance & scale penalties for C++ code at that time. While one still needs to be careful, the performance overhead of modern C++ on modern computers is much less of a concern, and is often an acceptable trade-off considering its security, readability, and maintainability benefits ... which is why we're steadily upgrading the Console’s code to modern C++.
>
> [Windows Command-Line: Inside the Windows Console](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-inside-the-windows-console/)

If you look into the [latest Windows Console’s internals structure](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/#comment-86865) you can see that it uses [`Map`, `Collection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/collections-c-cx?view=vs-2019) which suggests that it likely uses some [C++/CX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX)

[image: Windows Console Text Buffer Architecture]

> From the top (original buffer's blue boxes):
>
> - `ScreenInfo` – maintains information about the viewport, etc., and contains a TextBuffer
>
>   - `TextBuffer` – represents the Console’s text area as a collection of rows
>
>     - `Row` – uniquely represents each CharRow in the console and the formatting attributes applied to each row
>
>       - `CharRow` – contains a collection of CharRowCells, and the logic and state to handle row wrapping & navigation
>
>         - `CharRowCell` – contains the actual cell’s text, and a DbcsAttribute byte containing cell-specific flags

In case you're interested then conhost.exe has also been open sourced, under the form of the new Windows terminal

> The Windows console host, `conhost.exe`, is Windows' original command-line user experience. It implements Windows' command-line infrastructure, and is responsible for hosting the Windows Console API, input engine, rendering engine, and user preferences. The console host code in this repository is the actual source from which the `conhost.exe` in Windows itself is built.
>
> https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

You can find more pretty good articles with detailed information in the [Windows command line blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/)